# hapi authentication strategy karma test with sinon with async function

Tags: unit-testing, server, karma-runner, sinon, hapi

I am trying to test the authentication scheme with hapi server.  I have two helper function within the same file where I put my authentication scheme.  I want to test when this successfully authenticate the user.  But in my test case I always get 401 which is the unauthenicated message.

```
export const hasLegitItemUser = async (request, email, id) => {
  const {
    status,
    payload: {users}
  } = await svc.getRel(request, email);
  if (status !== STATUS.OK) {
    return false;
  }

  return users.includes(user) 
};

export const getUser = async request => {
  const token = request.state._token;
  const res = await svc.validateToken({request, token});
  const {
    userInfo: {email}
  } = res;
  const id = extractId(request.path);
  const isLetgitUser = await hasLegitItemUser(
    request,
    email,
    id
  );
  res.isLegitUser = isLegitUser;
  return res;
};


const scheme = (server, options) => {
  server.state("my_sso", options.cookie);

  server.ext("onPostAuth", (request, h) => {
    return h.continue;
  });

  return {
    async authenticate(request, h) {
      try {
        const {
          tokenValid,
          isLegitUser,
          userInfo
        } = await getUser(request);
        if (tokenValid && isLegitUser) {
          request.state["SSO"] = {
            TOKEN: request.state._token
          };

          return h.authenticated({
            credentials: {
              userInfo
            }
          });
        } else {
          throw Boom.unauthorized(null,"my_auth");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        throw Boom.unauthorized(null, "my_auth");
      }
    }
  };
};
```

My Test file:

```
import Hapi from "hapi";
import sinon from "sinon";
import auth, * as authHelpers from "server/auth";
import {expect} from "chai";
import pcSvc from "server/plugins/services/pc-svc";

describe("Authentication Plugin", () => {
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  const server = new Hapi.Server();
  const authHandler = request => ({
    credentials: request.auth.credentials,
    artifacts: "boom"
  });
before(() => {
    server.register({
      plugin: auth,
    });
const route = ["/mypage/{id}/home"];
    route.forEach(path => {
      server.route({
        method: "GET",
        path,
        options: {
          auth: auth,
          handler:{}
        }
      });
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

it("should authorize user if it is a validated user", async () => {
    sandbox
      .stub(authHelpers, "getUser")
      .withArgs(request)
      .resolves({
        tokenValid: true,
        isLegitUser: true,
        userInfo: {}
      });

    return server
      .inject({
        method: "GET",
        url:
          "/mypage/888/home"
      })
      .then(res => {
        expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(res.result).to.eql({
          userInfo: {
            email: "abc@gmail.com",
            rlUserId: "abc",
            userId: "abc@gmail.com"
          }
        });
      });
  });
});
```

I always get the 401 error for unauthenticated.  It seems like my "getUser" function in my test is not triggering for some reason, it goes straight to the throw statement in the catch phase in my code.  Please help.

Comment: What was the throw error message?

Comment: This is what I got:  
{
 statusCode: 401,
 error: "Unauthorized",
 message: "Missing authentication"
}
The try block was not successful so it went to the catch in the test.

Comment: Try to remove ```.withArgs(request)``` from your stub definition, because from your test file snippet, you have not defined request.